# How to disable TinyMCE confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Does anyone know how to disable TinyMCE alerts, and confirms. The confirm in talking about says:

> This page is asking you to confirm
>   that you want to leave - data you have
>   entered may not be saved Leave Page -
>   Stay on Page

I've written my own stuff that detects if the page data has been change so I don;t want TinyMCE to worry. I found the function in the TinyMCE source so I'm about to overwrite it but I want to know if anyone knows a better way to accomplish this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To remove the message, just disable the `autosave` plugin, that's what adds the `onunload` prompt.

Simply don't load the plugin in your TinyMCE initialization script.

Comment: Just disabled autosave as well as save and no luck. I'm using version version 3.9.3 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hmmm... I did find [this](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=82564), see if any of those 2 alternative solutions help. I'm on 3.6 I think and this works for me. Let me know how you make out.

Comment: Thanks for everything. Looks like some people were having the same problems I was. I posted my solution in the question.

Comment: Glad you found it, and thanks for sharing the solution! That's the way to do it! Glad to have more quality members here, cheers!

Comment: just removed `autosave` from the plugins to make this go away. 
using tinyMCE 4.0 on my project.

Answer (score 9):

As per a request I'm adding this here to show my solution which has worked great:

My solution thanks to a link provided by [Madmartigan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398242/madmartigan), on the [TinyMCE forum](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=82564). Getting rid of the autosave plugin did not work, I ended up writing this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {};
```

And it got rid of the popup. Looks like it could be a bug with TinyMCE, since the init code I have  I copied off their demo.

Answer (score 9):

I set it as a param when initializing (autosave_ask_before_unload):

```
tinymce.init({
        mode: 'textareas',
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        language: 'sv_SE',
        autosave_ask_before_unload: false,
        ...
```

Answer (score 4):

If the problem you're having is just that the content isn't actually dirty, maybe because you replaced it programmatically, you can explicitly mark the editor as not dirty like this:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.isNotDirty = true
```

Comment: I'm using an embedded an htm_editor instance (which is tinyMCE underneath) in my page and this is the only solution that worked for me to get rid of those dialogs! Thanks!

Comment: Very tnx is work in local 2022 version of tinyMce.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the above answers worked for me with Joomla 3.3.2 and JCE 2.5.11.  Although this did work:
Inside the file -

> components/com_jce/editor/tiny_mce/plugins/autosave/editor_plugin.js,

I changed

> editor.getParam("autosave_ask_before_unload",TRUE)

to

> editor.getParam("autosave_ask_before_unload",FALSE)

Apparently on autosave unload, it prompts the confirm box.  This disables the unload confirm completely.  From what I tested, it worked in IE, Chrome, and FF.